# openconnect VPN ceased to work after Fedora upgrade

Tags: fedora, gnome, vpn, openconnect

I recently upgraded to fedora 25. Since then my VPN connection via openconnect (Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN) ceased to work.

When I now try to define a new equivalent VPN connection, I get the message

```
Error: unable to load VPN connection editor
```

This appears under both, Wayland and X. I have
OpenConnect version v7.07; and I have NetworkManager-openconnect-1.2.4-1.fc25.x86_64.

Can you think of ways of getting the editor to work again? Or
Can you point to a way to manually define such a connection, circumventing gnome?

Comment: Are you using Wayland?

Comment: actually, not. I edited my question respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install:
NetworkManager-openconnect-gnome

Answer (score 3):

David above is correct. You need to install NetworkManager-openconnect-gnome.

```
sudo dnf install NetworkManager-openconnect-gnome
```

After I did this, the VPN settings dialog was restored, and I no longer had the "unable to load VPN connection editor" message.

Probably this is a new package for F25, so it wasn't already installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that during upgrade to F25 fedora removes the NetworkManager-openconnect package, and you need to re-install it. There is an open bug for it at:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398425

Comment: thanks, but that package is already installed.